# Git status not showing my PHP CodeSniffer auto code correction

Tags: php, git, vtiger, phpcodesniffer, vtigercrm

I am new to PHP CodeSniffer, I have git pulled PHP CodeSniffer in my Mac Machine and kept in **/var/www/PHP_CodeSniffer** and I have my source code in **/var/www/Project1.** I have git in **/var/www/Project1** and is now pointing to a branch **CodeCorrection**

When I run  **bin/phpcs ../Project1 -v** from **/var/www/PHP_CodeSniffer** folder it lists down many errors and when I run **bin/phpcbf ../Project1** It gives a summary of FIXED & REMAINING.

But no new file is showing as modified in git status. When I open the file also the change is not implemented or shown.

Once again if I run, I get report as same no of code FIXED & REMAINING

Can any one tell be what am I missing. My project is a Vtiger project.

Comment: Try running phpcbf with -v as well and see if there are any errors reported. Also maybe try running phpcbf on a single file directly and see what happens. I haven't seen any reports of phpcbf not overwriting files, so there isn't much more I can suggest.

Comment: I have tried phpcbf -v and also tried for single file. It shows  fixed & Remaining but the actual file is not changing. When I run again it shows the same error count fixed once again but the actual file is not changing.

Comment: try just adding in a comment char somewhere - see if git status picks it up

Comment: Yes If we do changes manually it shows in git status. I am trying to do code correction for a Vtiger project it has many internal folders will this be a problem.

Comment: @VijayanandPremnath are you sure codesniffer has correct permissions to change the code? may be able to tell you what it could change, but gets permissions error?

Answer (score 0):

Moving the source folder into the **PHP_CodeSniffer**  directory helped me to solve the issue.

Keeping the source folder outside the **PHP_CodeSniffer** and giving full permission did not help me.